# Avoid tensorflow session extension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a function which uses tensorflow backend from keras. In a **loop** I add operations to the session graph and then run the session. The problem is that the **graph seems to grow extensively** after multiple call to the function. This lead to having the function evaluation to be 2 times longer after 4/5 calls to the function.

This is the function:

```
def attack_fgsm(self, x, y, epsilon=1e-2):
    sess = K.get_session()
    nabla_x = np.zeros(x.shape)

    for (weak_classi, alpha) in zip(self.models, self.alphas):
        grads = K.gradients(K.categorical_crossentropy(y, weak_classi.model.output), weak_classi.model.input)[0]
        grads = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={weak_classi.model.input: x})
        nabla_x += alpha*grads

    x_adv = x + epsilon*np.sign(nabla_x)

    return x_adv
```

So the question is how to optimize this function so that the **graph doesn't grow** too much ?

After some research it seems that I need to use **placeholder** to overcome the problem. So I came up with this :

```
def attack_fgsm(self, x, y, epsilon=1e-2):
    sess = K.get_session()
    nabla_x = np.zeros(x.shape)
    y_ph = K.placeholder(y.shape)
    model_in = K.placeholder(x.shape, dtype="float")

    for (weak_classi, alpha) in zip(self.models, self.alphas):
        grads = K.gradients(K.categorical_crossentropy(y_ph, weak_classi.model.output), weak_classi.model.input)[0]
        grads = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={y_ph:y, model_in:x})
        nabla_x += alpha*grads

    x_adv = x + epsilon*np.sign(nabla_x)
    #K.clear_session()
    return x_adv
```

Which leads to :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/simond/adversarialboosting/src/scripts/robustness_study.py", line 93, in <module>
    x_att_ada = adaboost.attack_fgsm(x_test, y_test, epsilon=eps)
  File "/home/simond/adversarialboosting/src/classes/AdvBoostM1.py", line 308, in attack_fgsm
    grads = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={y_ph:y, model_in:x})
  File "/home/simond/miniconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/simond/miniconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1158, in _run
    self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
  File "/home/simond/miniconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 474, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/home/simond/miniconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 261, in for_fetch
    type(fetch)))
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is running this line of code each time you call this function:

```
grads = K.gradients(K.categorical_crossentropy(y, weak_classi.model.output), weak_classi.model.input)[0]
```

This adds a symbolic computation of the gradient to your graph, and it is not needed to be run more than once for each `weak_classi` instance, so you can split this into two parts. This part should be run only once, say, at initialization:

```
self.weak_classi_grads = []
for (weak_classi, alpha) in zip(self.models, self.alphas):
    grads = K.gradients(K.categorical_crossentropy(y_ph, weak_classi.model.output), weak_classi.model.input)[0]
self.weak_classi_grads.append(grads)
```

Then you can rewrite your evaluation function as:

```
def attack_fgsm(self, x, y, epsilon=1e-2):
    sess = K.get_session()
    nabla_x = np.zeros(x.shape)

    for (weak_classi, alpha, grads) in zip(self.models, self.alphas, self.weak_classi_grads):
        grads = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={weak_classi.model.input: x})
        nabla_x += alpha*grads

    x_adv = x + epsilon*np.sign(nabla_x)

    return x_adv
```

This way the graph only has one instance of gradient computation for each model, and then you just need to run the session to evaluate gradients with different inputs.